# TextView arrangment (to be placed at the end of the last line of previous textview)

Tags: android, textview

there are 2 `Textview` with different background color,, the second `Textview` has to be placed at the end of the first `textview's` last line. Where and how do i need to arrange the second `textview`?

[Here it shows what i need to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkMQS.png)

Comment: show the image of how you want to arrange them.

Comment: added the image

Comment: use 1 TextView with 2 Spannable strings (they are stylable, you can set different colors to them, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, we use HTML text for this information. 
We can use as many text styles as we want for different texts. With this way, you can set properties for each texts differently.

For Example: `<HTML><text1><text2></HTML>`

In the above, you can define text properties independently. Finally place this text in Textview. So we can achieve this using single TextView itself.

Example:

```
String str = "<a>This is a  <font color='#800000FF'> blue text</font> and this is a <font color='red'> red text</font> </a>";

TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
        android:text="Hello"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
<TextView
        android:text="world"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```